# CSS transform-origin + stacked divs

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am attempting to **rotate/spin-in-place** some **stacked** divs, but the 'transform-origin' property seems to be ignored when using absolute divs.

Attached is an example, the divs are stacked using stack class. Would using SVG be a better solution?

```css
.circle {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 50px solid white;
  margin: auto;
}

body {
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle_one {
  animation: rotateY 3s infinite linear;
}

.circle_two {
  animation: rotateX 2s infinite linear;
}

.spinMe {
  animation: spinMe 2s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

.stack {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateY {
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateX {
  to {
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinMe {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinMe">
<div class="circle circle_one stack"></div>
<div class="circle circle_two stack"></div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `spinMe` element has 100% width and zero height due to the absolutely positioned children. If you give `spinMe` a defined width and height equal to `.circle` it works correctly.

```css
.circle {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 50px solid white;
  margin: auto;
}

body {
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle_one {
  animation: rotateY 3s infinite linear;
}

.circle_two {
  animation: rotateX 2s infinite linear;
}

.spinMe {
  animation: spinMe 2s infinite linear;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  width: 350px;
  height: 350px;
}

.stack {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateY {
  to {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotateX {
  to {
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinMe {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinMe">
<div class="circle circle_one stack"></div>
<div class="circle circle_two stack"></div>  
</div>
```